# Kafka Java consumer marked as dead for group

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm using a Java consumer to consume messages from a topic (kafka version 0.10.0.1) which works fine if I run them outside of docker container. When I execute them in docker container, however, then the groups are marked as dead with message

```
Marking the coordinator local.kafka.com:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) dead for group my-group
```

My consumer configuration are as follows:-

```
metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
partition.assignment.strategy =[org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
bootstrap.servers = [192.168.115.128:9092, 192.168.115.128:9093]
ssl.keystore.type = JKS
enable.auto.commit = true
sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
interceptor.classes = null
exclude.internal.topics = true
ssl.truststore.password = null
client.id = consumer-1
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
max.poll.records = 2147483647
check.crcs = true
request.timeout.ms = 40000
heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
ssl.truststore.type = JKS
ssl.truststore.location = null
ssl.keystore.password = null
fetch.min.bytes = 1
send.buffer.bytes = 131072
value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
group.id = my-group
retry.backoff.ms = 100
sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
ssl.key.password = null
fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
session.timeout.ms = 30000
metrics.num.samples = 2
key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
ssl.protocol = TLS
ssl.provider = null
ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
ssl.keystore.location = null
ssl.cipher.suites = null
security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
auto.offset.reset = earliest
```

The `auto.commit` property is set to `false` and the `poll.timeout` is set to `10000`. Can somebody please point out where I am mistaken?

Comment: Have you solved this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be your advertised.listener (broker config) or lack thereof passing the consumer an incorrect URL back after the first discovery call from boostrap.servers in your consumer.

This can cause the consumer to use an incorrect URL for the rest of the RPC calls.

Answer (score 0):

In short this means inacitivity in the communication between broker consumer - in the `AbstractConsumer` the connection is terminated.

A reference to an actual implementation of mine in Spark streaming.

In the application our batches could last up to five minutes, therefore we adjusted the Kafka properties under these settings:

```
"heartbeat.interval.ms" -> "30000"
"session.timeout.ms" -> "90000"
"request.timeout.ms" -> "120000"
```

For the interval, this is a times-five of the original default value, which in the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html) is said to be suited for half minutes batches; pay attention you have to account for the extremely long batches (those which lag out).

The other two are just bigger than that because Kafka requires so.

A related configuration is:

```
spark.streaming.kafka.consumer.poll.ms
```

About this one, it might be meaningful to set it rather small, like ten seconds, under the rationale that if something goes wrong, then a setup with a high number of Spark task reattempts:

```
spark.task.maxFailures
```

will cover for this.

I have always found the configuration for KafkaSpark quite daunting, especially on the Kafka side.

The rule of thumb is always: go with the defaults, and override only if stricly needed.